# How to implement a progress bar in my project?

Tags: jquery, excel, razor, export, progress-bar

I have been looking at so many examples regarding progress bars that I have confused myself.

In my project I have a an excel.png icon which when clicked runs a page that exports table data to excel.

As you can understand compiling and exporting the data can take some time about 30+ seconds. This is enough time for users to start clicking other items because there is no indication that anything is happening.

The solution is of course a progress indicator and there are so many examples that show how the progress indicator can be built. However, I cannot see how the indicator can be used in my project, my difficulty is where to put the code and what does it look like.

My page that exports the data to excel is called GenSRPFLens.cshtml:

```
 @{    
      Layout = null;    

      var appData = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");    
      var originalFileName = "orgSRPLens.xls";    
      var newFileName = string.Format("{0}.xls", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());    
      var originalFile = Path.Combine(appData, originalFileName);    
      var newFile = Path.Combine(appData, newFileName);    
      File.Copy(originalFile, newFile);

      var lenscat =Database.Open("A-LensCatFE-01SQL");
      var CustomerCode = !UrlData[0].IsEmpty()?UrlData[0]:"1";

      var sql = "Select * from dbo.qryDiscountLensPrice WHERE CustomerCode=@0 Order by LensForm, LensCode";
      var srplensdata = lenscat.Query(sql, CustomerCode);

      var connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0}/{1};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'", appData, newFileName);    
      var provider = "System.Data.OleDb";    
      using (var SRPLens = Database.OpenConnectionString(connString, provider)){
          sql = @"INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (CustomerCode,  LensCode, LensForm, ShortName, Description, [Index], Discount, LensMultFactor, DispensingFee, VAT, VATRate, SRPBasedOn, iScription, Cost, DiscountPrice, NoVATprice, AddVAT, SRP)           
                VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16,@17)";

    foreach(var LensCode in srplensdata){            
       SRPLens.Execute(sql, 
       LensCode.CustomerCode,                
       LensCode.LensCode,                
       LensCode.LensForm,                 
       LensCode.ShortName,                 
       LensCode.Description,                 
       LensCode.Index,  
       LensCode.Discount,
       LensCode.LensMultFactor,
       LensCode.DispensingFee,
       LensCode.VAT,
       LensCode.VATRate,
       LensCode.SRPBasedOn,    
       LensCode.iScription,           
       LensCode.Cost,                 
       LensCode.DiscountPrice,
       LensCode.NoVATPrice,
       LensCode.AddVAT,
       LensCode.SRP);        
        }    
        }    
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SRPFLens.xls");    
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";    
        Response.TransmitFile(newFile);    
        Response.Flush();    
        File.Delete(newFile);    
        Response.End();


}
```

The part that calls the above page is in a page called DiscountCustomers.cshtml:

```
<img src="/images/ExcelIconGreen25x25.png" id="SRPLens" alt="Export SRP Lens" title="Export SRP F Data to Excel: Lens" />

@section script{   
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#SRPLens').live('hover', function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });
        $('#SRPLens').live('click', function ()  {
            $('<iframe src=@linkSRPFLens></iframe>').appendTo('body').hide();        
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a progress bar .css file called progressbarT2.css:

```
#progressBar {
        width: 150px;
        height: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #111;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;    margin-top: 10px;    margin-left: 20px; 
        visibility: visible;

}
#progressBar div {
        height: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 7px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
        width: 0;
        background-color: #b200ff;
```

}

Then I get stuck, there are so many examples that I cannot make any sense of what the code should be and where it should be placed to get this to work. Your guidance is needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="progressBar"> <div>
```

css:

```
#progressBar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color: #292929;
}



#progressBar div {
        height: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
        width: 0;
        background-color: #0099ff;
}
```

js:

```
  function progress(percent, $el) {
            var progressBarWidth = percent * $el.width() / 100;
            $el.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
        }

  var globalP = 0;

        var startProgressBar = function(){
            if(globalP < 100){
                globalP = globalP + 1;
                progress(globalP, $('#progressBar')); 
                setTimeout(startProgressBar, 500); 
            }
            else {
                //done
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            startProgressBar();
        })
```

for complete gist:

https://gist.github.com/railscash/5804857

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my Q is where do the various elements go and how do I call them in my project. For example where do I put the div, and does your js go in a page called progress.js or does it go directly into a page and which page? The link you have provided is the one I am looking at already but I can get the bar but I cannot get it to load when the icon is clicked... further help on this would be very cool...

Comment: @Munatasim, once again thank you for your valuable help. However, I think what I need is a bit more complex than I thought. I want to give an indication to the user that a database function is running and compiling data which will be retrieved as an excel which the user can then open, save or cancel. It is while this is happening that I need my progress bar to pop up , progress from left to right from 0% to 100%, exit as the database function completes. Hence, the example you have kindly provided may not be suitable for my needs. What do you think?

Comment: can you predict how much will it take to complete? if yes then its possible implement that.

Comment: The longest it will take is about 90 seconds. avg is 30 seconds. So are you saying that the sample you have provided will work for me to show the progress of the DB query? If so that is good. Now I need a bit more help, can you tell me where do I put the div? and where do I put the js code? Once again thanks.

Comment: put the div where you want to show the progress bar. You can control the progress bar position using css. Now Js: put the js (except the document.ready block ) anywhere in the page. Now when your upload starts call `startProgressBar();`.

To get more flexibility, you can set an ajax request to get the status of the uploading process, if the uploading completed set the global variable `globalP = 100`. The progress bar will show 100% and it will stop.  Hope that helps, thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, by now you will have understood that I am a noob in this field and this is a steep curve. Please bear with me and my stooopid Qs. OK this is what I have done: Put the div in the CustomerDiscount page which contains the icon and where I want the progress to pop up. Now which page do I put the js - CustomerDiscount or GenSRPFLens or somewhere else. and what do you mean by call startProgressBar() and again where does it go? Sorry for so many Q, now u can see why I am here!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31995/discussion-between-muntasim-and-liquidmetal)

Comment: Sorry buddy still stuck on the hide part of the progress bar code, any chance for some more guidance if you don't mind?

Comment: actually I didnt test in IE, if you can test in other browsers like crome, firefox then let me know

Comment: The code you have given to me is working ok just need help to hide the bar once the bar has completed the animation to 100%

Comment: you have to hide the progress bar when done. Here is the updated code. please notice the else block. It removes the progress bar using `$('#progressBar').hide();`

    `var startProgressBar = function(){
            if(globalP < 100){
                globalP = globalP + 1;
                progress(globalP, $('#progressBar')); 
                setTimeout(startProgressBar, 500); 
            }
            else {
               
              $('#progressBar').hide(); 
            }
        }`